# Typescript doesn't add prototype.constructor during transpilation

Tags: typescript

Following is TS class.

```
class TestA {
  name: string;

  constructor(name:string){
    this.name = name;
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  getCName(): string {
    return TestA.prototype.constructor.name;
  }
}

let ta = new TestA('ta');
```

And below is the transpiled JS

```
var TestA = (function () {
    function TestA(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    TestA.prototype.getName = function () {
        return this.name;
    };
    TestA.prototype.getCName = function () {
        return TestA.prototype.constructor.name;
    };
    return TestA;
}());
var ta = new TestA('ta');
//# sourceMappingURL=TestA.js.map
```

Issue: 1:
As one can see there is no constructor property set on TestA prototype. In my application I need it. I am using inheritance and knowing the type of of object is vital as I am converting class objects to and from JSON. Could you please suggest me any tweak to TS compiler that can do it.

Otherwise I will have to manually set it for every class that I create.

Issue 2:

In the generated JS all functions are anonymous. Is there a way to give them name like . This is also extremely helpful during debugging. Could any one suggest me a way to do it too.

Thanks for reading and taking interest in the post. 
-Manish

Comment: Why are you using `prototype.constructor.name` rather than just `prototype.name`?

Comment: The constructor property on the prototype is set automatically for you. That's how things have worked for years. `TestA.prototype.constructor.name` would work fine if `TestA.prototype.constructor` (which is exactly the same as `TestA`) **did** have a `name` property, which it does not. For example, if you wrote `static name = "Bob";`, then `TestA` would have `name` property.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and running demo. I guess problem was es5. For second issue I am just doing regex replacement after compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor in ES5 is the function:

```
function TestA(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

The `constructor` keyword was added in ES6 and therefor not used when transpiling to ES5.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript automatically provides the `prototype.constructor` property for a function ... and since Typescript doesn't replace the `prototype` field completely the `constructor` field [will still be there](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20TestA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(name%3Astring)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20getName()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20getCName()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20TestA.prototype.constructor.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20ta%20%3D%20new%20TestA('ta')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(ta.getCName())):

```
class TestA {
  name: string;

  constructor(name:string){
    this.name = name;
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  getCName(): string {
    return TestA.prototype.constructor.name;
  }
}

let ta = new TestA('ta');

alert(ta.getCName());
// alerts TestA
```